# Import ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-import-export

I have a **ManyToMany** field in my models.

I want to import data and enter into that field.

My **Resources.py**:-

```
class ClinicResource(resources.ModelResource):
language = fields.Field(column_name='language',attribute='language', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Language, 'code'))
country = fields.Field(column_name='country',attribute='country', widget=ClinicCountryForeignKeyWidget(model = Country, field ='name'))
clinic_languages = fields.Field(widget=ManyToManyWidget(ClinicLanguages, field='name'))

class Meta:
    model = Clinic
    fields = ('code', 'name', 'city', 'score')
    exclude = ('id',)
    import_id_fields = ('code', 'name', 'city', 'score', 'language', 'country')
```

my ***Models.py***:-

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length= 10, blank= False, null= False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 256, blank= False, null= False)
    slug = models.SlugField(null= True, blank= True)
    # country = models.CharField(max_length= 256, blank= False, null= False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length= 256, blank= False, null= False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allcliniccountry', blank= True, null=True)
    score = models.FloatField(blank= False, null= False, default= 2, validators=[MinValueValidator(min), MaxValueValidator(max)])
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allclinicslanguage', blank= True)
    # about = models.TextField(blank= True, null= True)
    clinic_languages = models.ManyToManyField(ClinicLanguages, related_name='clinic_language', blank= True)

    about = tinymce_models.HTMLField(blank= True, null= True)
    created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 30, choices= SIZE_CHOICES, default= 'pending', blank= False, null= False)
```

***NOTE THE clinic_languages field, this is what I want to import***

Comment: Your question is not clear. In `models.ManyToManyField()` you must pass the name of the model which is related to many to many relationships with `Clinic` model. In your case, if `ClinicLanguages` has many to many relationship with `Clinic` then you can proceed

Comment: @NetraPdNeupane It is working in the admin panel.. But i dont know how to import data by csv for this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how the `ManyToManyWidget` works in the django-import-export [source](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/033f803c5994ceba9da8b610819ee5b52a630bf7/import_export/widgets.py#L428).

You have defined your field correctly:

```py
clinic_languages = fields.Field(widget=ManyToManyWidget(ClinicLanguages, field='name'))
```

This means the lookup code is going to attempt to load related instances using the 'name' field.  By default, they have to be separated by ',' in your import file, e.g:

```
clinic_languages
name1,name2,name3
```

You can override the separator if necessary.